# How to make Resharper format line-wrapped ternary operators in the following way

Tags: c#, resharper, ternary-operator

I really want Resharper to format my line-wrapped ternaries in this way

```
return
    navigator.IsTerminating ?
    navigator.Context :
    navigator.Context.GetSimulatableRelative(new Navigator(navigator));
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: This use case is somewhat challenging because I think what you're essentially after is a condition that there's a line break after the `return` statement if and only if the statement being returned is a ternary expression of sufficient size. (Or would you also line-break if it was a simple as `x>y?1:0`?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is an out of the box way of doing this. The only way i know to influence how R# formats code is through these settings:

Resharper --> Options... --> Langauges --> C# --> Formatting Style

[image: Resharper Options Screenshot]

This doesn't allow you to write your own custom formatting rules though.

If you feel like a challenge then you could write a plugin. There is some docs and an SDK:

- [Developer Docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6+Plugin+Development)
- [SDK](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/)
- [A video tutorial](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/01/introducing-resharper-61-sdk/)

Answer (score 1):

much Not answering resharper issue, but for what its worth, I've always found it much clearer to put the operators up front (left-hand-side) so it is clear from the start what you are looking at, especially if lines are long ie...

```
  return
      navigator.IsTerminating 
        ? navigator.Context
        : navigator.Context.GetSimulatableRelative(new Navigator(navigator));
```