# Resharper formatting for single-line if statement

Tags: c#, resharper

Is there a setting in ReSharper to automatically format single-statement IF statments with the braces block on a one line? This is on ReSharper 6.1.

```
//What I want
if(tired)
{ Sleep(); }
else
{ Party(); }


//what I get 
if(tired)
{
    Sleep();
}
else
{
    Party();
}
```

Comment: This is quite similar to another question i have just posted an answer to. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10058025/459517

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if it would be, *i* personally would suggest do not use it, cause it's *non readable*.

I, *personally*, can accept

```
if(tired)
    Sleep();
else
    Party()
```

but not something you're searching for.

Good luck